# FB App works in Iframe, but doesn't appear when used as Page Tab

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs, facebook-iframe

Okay, allow me to say first off that I am working on developing my first FB app/page tab at the moment.  I'm not looking for anything fancy yet, just workability.

That being said, I have managed to create a FB app that loads from the hosting requested, and displays it under the app page.  I have also made it so that I can add it as a page tab to FB pages.  What I am having an issue with is that clicking on the page tab for the app, it does not show any content in the iframe on the page, though it shows on the canvas page for the app.

So, my question is, do you have any ideas as to why it might be showing on a canvas iframe and not the page tab iframe?  I am currently guessing that it has to do with how the signed request is processed, but am not completely sure.  I am using the PHP SDK for FB given here: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/ for the FB-related functions, and am tracing through that currently for where I might be going wrong.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.  =)

Comment: what are your settings? when editing the application you have to define the url to both app and page tab.

Comment: The canvas URL (which I'm testing to see if FB is reading the site) is set to the base URL (https://cold-robot-7534.herokuapp.com/ in this case), while the page tab URL is set to the main page of this ( https://cold-robot-7534.herokuapp.com/index.php ).  Both Secure and non-secure are provided (same URL).  Discovery is on, it's out of sandbox, and is a web app, with fluid canvas size (though I have set the width in the index.php to be 520 px).

Comment: does your server support ssl? the fb docu says: Users browsing in HTTPS will be unable to use your tab if this URL is empty. Note that your page tab app must support SSL by October 1, 2011.

Comment: The server does support ssl.  As far as I can tell, it wouldn't be visible in the FB canvas page if it didn't.  The app is visible, located here: http://apps.facebook.com/localartists/ , but simply not on the tab, example here: http://www.facebook.com/supportthepeople?sk=app_146678205429662

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it by providing different (http vs https) URLs for the secure and non-secure canvas and page tab URLs. Just remove post the non-secure URL for the non-secure canvas/page tab URL fields. I believe this is because Facebook doesn't check to see if the user has secure browsing turned on until after they have logged in.

Comment: The answer provided by Doppelganger appears to be correct.  Thank you.  =)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the order of appear of the app tab; it worked for me.